# MOSFET is not turning on in bidirectional power switch circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, embedded, atmega, mppt

I am designing an MPPT circuit using bidirectional power switch(as load switch)having two PMOS connected back to back and both the MOSFEts are driven by BC847 transistor that is being driven by a microcontroller(atmega 32). The problem is that it is not turning the MOSFET on.
The base is connected to one of the GPIO pins of the controller that is shown below in the schematic.
BAT_CON is connected to PC6,

[image]

**MPPT_out+** =14v
**BAT_CON** = 4.9V
**Hfe of BC847**=200
**Vcc**=14v,**Vsat**=0.2v

Comment: `The base is connected to one of the ADC pins of the controller that is shown below in the schematic.` I can't see such thing. Are you trying to drive the Q3 with ADC? Sorry, I couldn't understand.

Comment: If you are driving Q3 from a GPIO output having 4.9V output voltage level then R2 seems to be too big to saturate Q3. Decrease it to something like 30k. You can replace Q3 with a logic-level-gate NMOS such as 2N700x do decrease the drive current, but in either case you may want to decrease R2.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I did calculate the value of R2 by referring to the datasheet and taking into account the Vcc, Vsat & Rc and it came as 100k.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have updated my schematic, you can check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, an ADC pin is an input, not an output, and cannot drive a transistor into saturation.  A GPIO pin in an output mode can do this.  So can a DAC pin if it is programmed correctly.

Second, 300K is way to large a value for R2 in this application.  The rule of thumb for "hard"  or "firm" saturation is that the base current be no less than 1/10th of the collector current (up to the transistor's max base current rating).  Your collector current is 1.4 mA.  This yields a calculated R2 value of approx. 30 K.

That is an OK starting point, but the base current is only 140 uA.  There is no harm in increasing the base current, and it reduces the circuit's sensitivity to electrical noise.  For parts commonality, I recommend 10 K for R2.  For even better noise immunity, reduce it to 4.7 K.

Comment: sorry I forgot to update my schematic. Now I have updated it and so calculated the values accordingly, you can check it now. The pin was GPIO pin (ADC was typo).

Comment: Decreasing R3 increased its power dissipation to over 1/8 W.  For decent reliability, it should be at least a 1/4 W part.  And I still think R2 is too large.

Comment: Then, what resistance value do  you suggest across base terminal ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "across base terminal.  R2 is in series with the base, 
 As stated in the answer - 4.7 K to 10 K.  There is no need for a pulldown resistor from the base to GND.

Comment: Circuit worked by replacing 1.5k with 10k and 100k with 300k. (hfe=200 according to datasheet)

Comment: Assuming that a transistor will work identically under all physical conditions and variations from batch to batch is not good design practice.  You are using the part as a linear amplifier in a circuit that benefits from a saturated switch.  Recalculate assuming that hfe = 20.  Note that in a circuit like this, there is not one perfect value for either resistor.